# Generate a Point object randomly excluding certain values

Tags: java, arraylist, stream

I have an Arraylist which contains some **Points** objects.

```
private List<Point> snakeXY = Arrays.asList(new Point(10,5), new Point(11,5), new Point(12,5),new Point(13,5) );
```

I want to generate  an **Point object**( new Point(x, y) ) randomly with **x** and **y** between **1 and 30(*exclude*)** and that is different from any Point object present in the snakeXY ArrayList. **For example** you can have a Point object with the values **(14,5)** or **(15,29)** or **(5,12)** but **not** **(12,5)** or **(13,5)** because they are already present in snakeXY.

I have the feeling that i have to use Streams but I don't see how?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is it your own `Point` class or something like `java.awt.Point`?

Comment: it is java.awt.Point

Comment: @HenryTwist I'm sorry but it doesn't help me much, my problem is that the number of objects in snakeXY can increase, it is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see an alternative to creating a pool of candidate points, which will hold all possible points on the `30x30` grid minus the points already in `snakeXY`, and selecting a random point from this pool. You can minimize the cost by using the `int` encoding of point position, rather than actually creating `Point` objects.

We first build a `Set` of point positions to exclude:

```
List<Point> snakeXY = Arrays.asList(new Point(10,5), new Point(11,5), new Point(12,5),new Point(13,5) );

int min = 2;
int max = 30;
int n = max - min;
Set<Integer> exclude = new HashSet<>();
for(Point p : snakeXY)
    exclude.add((p.y-min)*n + (p.x-min));
```

We then use a list to hold a pool of possible point positions:

```
List<Integer> pool = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) 
    if(!exclude.contains(i)) pool.add(i);
```

Now we simply select a random position from our pool and create the corresponding `Point` object:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int p = rand.nextInt(pool.size());
int pi = pool.get(p);
Point pt = new Point(min + (pi % n), min + (pi / n));
System.out.println(pt);
```

If we want to generate multiple points we need to remove the selected point position from the pool.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    int p = rand.nextInt(pool.size());
    int pi = pool.remove(p);
    Point pt = new Point(min + (pi % n), min + (pi / n));
    System.out.println(pt);
}
```

Comment: I can say that you understood my problem perfectly. I will try your code and keep you informed.

Comment: and if i want just the y-coordinate to be in 2(include) and 30 (exclude), how should i have to modify your hashfunction?

Comment: I've updated the answer to support the specification of a `min(inclusive)` and a `max(exclusive)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Point generateRandomPoint(List<Point> snakeXY) {
        List<Integer> xToExclude = snakeXY.stream().map(it -> (int) it.getX()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> yToExclude = snakeXY.stream().map(it -> (int) it.getY()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new Point(nextIntInRangeButExclude(1, 30, xToExclude), nextIntInRangeButExclude(1, 30, yToExclude));
    }

public int nextIntInRangeButExclude(int start, int end, List<Integer> excludes) {
        int rangeLength = end - start - excludes.size();
        int randomInt = new Random().nextInt(rangeLength) + start;
        for (Integer i : excludes) {
            if (i > randomInt) {
                return randomInt;
            }
            randomInt++;
        }

        return randomInt;
    }
```

Basically, I have no idea how you can achieve it using JUST streams. However  `xToExclude` and `yToExclude` are arrays with points you already have for `x` and `y` in your array. `nextIntInRangeButExclude` method gives you a random number excluding points that you have. Having two random numbers that you don't already have allows you to create not existent random point.

Comment: @HenryTwist, I don't want to exclude a particular x and y, but rather a couple of values (x,y). In other words the randomly generated object must have different coordinates than the objects in snakeXY.

Comment: your code excludes x-coordinates independently of y-coordinates present in snakeXY. I would like to exclude here the (x,y) pairs already present in snakeXY.